# Default MVC4 Template changing dbcontext without changing database name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i've created a default MVC4 Template Template with authorization. Now i like to add a model (TestModel) to my dbcontext.

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TestModel> TestModel { get; set; }
}
```

After i changed the dbcontext i've to delete the database and change the name. Is there a more comfortable way ?

Answer (score 1):

The context and the database don't always have to be the same name. You can define the name of your database in your connection string by using `Initial Catalog=DbNameGoesHere`.
This way you can rename your context all you want and the database name is always the same.

Comment: i'know its annoying trough